# TranslateTransform from codebehind not working

Tags: c#, animation, storyboard

I want to apply an animation from codebehind to various controls. That is basically working fine for opacity animations applied to an Image control. But if I want to do the same for a TranslateTransform animation simply nothing happens (it should slide in from the side). When I check tutorials it looks to me that I did it correctly, but there must be a mistake that I just do not see.

Here is my code, any good idea is well appreciated.

```
DoubleAnimation animation = new DoubleAnimation();
animation.From = -100;
animation.To = 0;
animation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
animation.EasingFunction = new ExponentialEase() { EasingMode = EasingMode.EaseOut };

Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, imageContainer);
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, new PropertyPath(TranslateTransform.XProperty));
            
Storyboard sb = new Storyboard();
sb.Children.Add(animation);

sb.Begin();
```

Comment: I guess you have not set TranslateTransform in LayoutTransform or RenderTransform of target element.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand what you mean. Do you think of something like this:

`imageContainer.RenderTransform = new TranslateTransform(0,0);`

I tried this one, but it still does not animate.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I finally found the solution using a different approach. I am not sure why it is not working with code above, even if I apply animation not to imagecontainer but to imageContainer.RenderTransform.
However this code is working:

```
imageContainer.RenderTransform = new TranslateTransform(-200, 0);
Duration duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5));
DoubleAnimation anim = new DoubleAnimation(0, duration);
anim.EasingFunction = new ExponentialEase() { EasingMode = EasingMode.EaseOut };

imageContainer.RenderTransform.BeginAnimation(TranslateTransform.XProperty, anim);
```